# how to search FB friends in our friend list using Graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

How to search our friends by name in our Facebook friend list?

In my program, I am listing all my friends using api in a box. In that box, there is one field- search for searching our friends. I want to search my friends using Graph api. But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FB doesn't provide any api for searching a specific user's friends, but it's easy to do it by yourself. I recommend you use [facebook-php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk).

1.

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

from now on, `$friends` is a list of user's friend. it equals accessing `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=USER_TOKEN` manually.

2.
suppose `$target` is a string from your search field

```
foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
    if (strpos($value["name"], $target) !== false) {
        // DO SOMETHING YOU WANT TO
    }
}
```

By the way, using javascript to search friend on client side may be more efficient and dynamical than using php. Personally, I would do it in the front end. Suppose you are using jQuery, and `target` is a string from your search field.

```
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=USER_TOKEN'
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    friends = data['data'];

    for(i in friends){ 
        if (friends[i]['name'].search(target) != -1){
            // DO SOMETHING YOU WANT TO
        }
    }
});
```